# ¿como puedo sumar días a una fecha con JDateChooser?

Tags: java

He intentado sumar días a una fecha determinada de tal manera que si tengo la fecha **2020-01-22** y deseo sumarle 10 días el resultado sea **2020-02-01**.

He intentado realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
 public static String sumarDiasAFecha(String fecha, int dias) {
        if(dias == 0){
            return fecha;
        }

        String[] f = fecha.split("-");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        //calendar.setTime(new Date(Integer.parseInt(f[0]), Integer.parseInt(f[1]), Integer.parseInt(f[2])));
        calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(f[0]), Integer.parseInt(f[1]), Integer.parseInt(f[2]));

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dias);
        SimpleDateFormat fe = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
        return fe.format(calendar.getTime());

    }
```

he tenido éxito, sin embargo poseo un pequeño problema ya que si hacemos el ejemplo anterior con fecha **2020-01-22** y sumo 10 días, el resultado es **2020-03-01**; es decir suma los días perfectamente, pero a su vez suma un mes mas, no importa los días de suma siempre suma un mes mas.

Utilizo la librería `JDateChooser` para recuperar la fecha base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de tener en cuenta que los meses en `Calendar`, van de 0 a 11, es decir el mes 0 es Enero, y el 11 es Diciembre, es por ello que aumenta un mes.

```
calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(f[0]), Integer.parseInt(f[1]), Integer.parseInt(f[2]));
```

En la línea anterior, estás pasando el numero tal cual, sin restar una unidad, entonces cuando pasas **2020-01-22** al sacar el `1` que corresponde al mes, no estás haciendo referencia a Enero si no a Febrero.

Debería ser:

```
calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(f[0]), Integer.parseInt(f[1])-1, Integer.parseInt(f[2]));
```

Al restar una unidad en `Integer.parseInt(f[1])-1`, en tu caso estarás haciendo referencia al mes correcto, que es el formato que utiliza `Calendar`, como lo especifica en el siguiente [enlace](http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:Calendar.MONTH).

Comment: Perfecto ese era el error, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro de ayudar :)

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar un ajuste recuerda que tienes que restar -1 al mes ingresado:

```
calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(f[0]), Integer.parseInt(f[1])-1, Integer.parseInt(f[2]));
```

puedes ver la razòn en el còdigo fuente :

> **@param month el valor utilizado para establecer el campo de calendario  `MONTH` . El valor del mes está basado en 0.
>   por ejemplo, 0 para enero.**

Por lo tanto el primer mes inicia en 0.

---

De esta forma obtendràs el resultado deseado:

```
public static String sumarDiasAFecha(String fecha, int dias) {
    if(dias == 0){
        return fecha;
    }

    String[] f = fecha.split("-");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //calendar.setTime(new Date(Integer.parseInt(f[0]), Integer.parseInt(f[1]), Integer.parseInt(f[2])));
    calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(f[0]), Integer.parseInt(f[1])-1, Integer.parseInt(f[2]));

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dias);
    SimpleDateFormat fe = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
    return fe.format(calendar.getTime());

}
```

Ejemplo:

```
System.out.println(sumarDiasAFecha("2020-01-22", 10));
```

Salida:

```
2020-02-01
```

Comment: Es correcto, mil gracias.

Comment: Excelente Jorge, saludos!